# Maven - deploying large war files

Tags: java, maven-2, deployment, tomcat

This question is somewhat similar to this one [Best way to deploy large *.war to tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185057/best-way-to-deploy-large-war-to-tomcat) so it's a good read first, but keep on reading my q, it's different at the end...

Using maven 2 my war files are awfully large (60M). I deploy them to a set of tomcat servers and just copying the files takes too long (it's about 1m per war).

On top of that I added an RPM layer that'll package the war in an RPM file (using maven's rpm plugin). When the RPM is executed on the target machine it'll cleanup, "install" the war (just copy it), stop and start the tomcat (that's how we do things here, no hot deploys) and set up a proper context file in place. This all works fine.
The problem, however, is that the RPM files are too large and slow to copy. What take almost eh entire space is naturally the war file.

I haven't seen any off-the-shelf solution so I'm thinking of implementing one myself so I'll describe it below and this description will hopefully help explain the problem domain.  I'll be happy to hear your thought on the planned solution, and better yet point me at other existing solutions and random tips.

The war files contain:

1. Application jars
2. 3rd party jars
3. resources (property files and other resources)
4. WEB-INF files such as JSPs, web.xml, struts.xml etc

Most of the space is taken by #2, the 3rd party jars.
The 3rd party jars are also installed on an internal nexus server we have in the company so I can take advantage of that.

You probably guessed that by now, so the plan is to create thin wars that'll include only the application jars (the ones authored by my company), resources and WEB-INF stuff and add smartness to the RPM install script that'll copy the 3rd party jars when needed.
RPM allows you to run arbitrary scripts before or after installation so the plan is to use mvn write a list of 3rd party dependencies when building the war and add it as a resource to the RPM and then when installing an RPM the RPM installation script will run over the list of required 3rd party jars and download the new jars from nexus only if they don't exist yet.
The RPM will have to delete jars if they are not used.
The RPM will also have to either rebuild the war for tomcat to explode it or add the 3rd party jars to common/lib or something like that although we have a few web-apps per tomcat so it'll make things complicated in that sense. Maybe explode the jar by itself and then copy the 3rd party jars to WEB-INF/lib

Your input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a directory on the target machines with all third party jars we're using (about 110Mb). The jars are using a naming coding convention that includes their version number (asm-3.2.jar, asm-2.2.3.jar ...). When adding a new version of a third party we don't delete the older version.

When deploying, our jar files contains only business logic classes and resources we compile in the build (no third party). The classpath is defined in the [jar manifest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) where we cherry pick which third party it should be using at runtime. We're doing that with ant, no maven involved and we have more then 25 types of services in our system (very "soa" though I dislike this over buzzed word). That business logic jar is the only jar in the jvm classpath when starting the process and it is also versioned by our code repo revision number. If you go back to older revision (rollback) of our code that might be using an older third party jar its still going to work as we don't remove old jars. New third party jars should be propagated to production machines before the business code that uses them does. But once they're there they're not going to be re-pushed on each deployment.

Overall we lean towards simplicity (i.e. not OSGi) and we don't use Maven.

Comment: Eishay, thanks, simplicity is certainly a worthwhile. I have taken a look at OSGi and although it has some compelling features I must say I'm not convinced its the right bang for the buck. I think I'll go with a solution b/w what you suggest and what I had in mind, while using the manifest's classpath

Comment: yet unfortunately, tomcat doesn't seem to support this method of operation :( MANIFEST.MF Class-Path is ignored in tomcat. By design http://markmail.org/message/fekqhwpakxvsfblx

Comment: This solution sounds a lot like re-inventing OSGi (again). Doing custom classpath and dependency management to allow for thin artifacts and modularity is exactly what OSGi was designed for. Is re-inventing the wheel really better than just putting an axle on your car?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against your proposed plan. It sounds like a lot of moving pieces that are likely hard to test and/or diagnose problem when they arise.

We don't have the problem of "large" WARs but we do have the problem that most of our WARs all need the exact same 3-rd party libraries on their classpath. The solution we went forth with (that has worked very well) was to utilize OSGi to build our application modularly. We use Felix as our OSGi container which runs inside of Tomcat. We then deploy all of our dependencies/libraries to Felix **once**. Then we deploy "thin" WARs which just reference OSGi dependencies by Importing the packages it needs from the bundles it cares about.

This has a few other advantages:

- Deploying new versions of OSGi bundles while the old ones are running is not an issue which allows for no downtime (similar to hot deploy).
- If you need to upgrade one of your dependencies (e.g. Spring 2.5 -> 3.0), you only need to upgrade the Spring bundle running in OSGi; no need to deliver (or package) new WARs if the APIs did not change. This can all (once again) be done on a live running OSGi container, no need to turn anything off.
- OSGI guarantees your bundles do not share classpaths. This helps keep your code cleaner because each WAR only needs knowledge of what it cares about.

Setting up your WARs to be "OSGi ready" is not trivial but it is well documented. Try checking out [How to get started with OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/About/HowOSGi) or just Google for 3rd party tutorials. Trust me, the initial investment will save you much time and many headaches in the future.

It is probably best not to re-invent the modularity *wheel* if possible.

Comment: I'm considering adding osgi support but I have to be honest, first, it doesn't completely solve the problem end to end as I have to copy the required jars (bundles) to the osgi container and second, osgi is a complicated beast and I still don't know whether it's worth my and other coworkers effort. But the pointers you provided I definitely helpful so thanks!