# looking for best ways to create and deploy web application into a single tomcat server automatically

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I have requirement like below ,

I need to  create and deploy web application into a single tomcat server automatically .

Can you please give suggestions on below:

1 . If I deploy one web application tomcat will automatically reloaded , will it affect other web applications which are already deployed ?

2 . To deploy new web applications I choose hot  deployment as I need to automate it I directly copy it to webapps folders .  Is this process is correct? what are the best ways?

3 . how the number of applications that tomcat will hold will be calculated , I mean based based on what factors , I am going to use big amount RAMs .

Can any body explain me the best ways to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Here general considerations links to this kind of question :

- [The simplest way to deploy to production with builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279441/the-simplest-way-to-deploy-to-production-with-builds/10964696#10964696)
- [Hot code deploy tomcat with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542108/hot-code-deploy-tomcat-with-maven)
- [Best way to deploy large *.war to tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185057/best-way-to-deploy-large-war-to-tomcat)
- http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-tomcat.html

To give you stratight answers :

> 1. If I deploy one web application tomcat will automatically reloaded , will it affect other web applications which are already deployed ?

No, it won't using tomcat or cargo plugin.

> 2 . To deploy new web applications I choose hot deployment as I need to automate it I directly copy it to webapps folders . Is this process is correct? what are the best ways?

Yes there are, once again using cargo or tomcat plugin. Your way is acceptable, but not optmial (to deal with deployement or order issues)

> 3 . how the number of applications that tomcat will hold will be calculated , I mean based based on what factors , I am going to use big amount RAMs

I'm not really sure to understand. You mean : How many application will you tomcat will be able to support ? It depends on how many objects each one uses or have in memory / session, times the number of session. There is no general rules to calculate it.

Answer (score 2):

For points 1 and 2 you need to look at the various hot deployment options in tomcat. Based on which solution you choose the behavior will be different. Simply copying the application into webapps directory might not work properly.
I would recommend using tomcat manager via your code using some HTTP client library. Be sure to read the documentation for tomcat manager before you keep it enabled on your server. There are other technologies as well - you can google for "Tomcat Hot Deployment" and find out

> 3 . how the number of applications that tomcat will hold will be
>   calculated , I mean based based on what factors , I am going to use
>   big amount RAMs .

This is dependent on your applications and how much memory they consume. Do consider the memory consumed by each of the connected users and tomcat's own memory overhead when calculating how much RAM you require.